# How to bind USB control knobs to adjust the volume on specific applications?

Tags: usb, macros, autohotkey, midi

I want to control the volume level of 2 specific Windows Applications using my USB piano's control knobs (Spotify Premium & discord).

FIRST TRY - AutoHotkey. The KeyHistory does not detect any input from the USB piano, so I stopped there.

SECOND TRY - 'MIDI Macros' - I use a 3rd party program called 'MIDI Macros' from mediachance.com - it has great functionality for binding hotkeys and running executables, but the scripting function is limited to mathematical operations and keystroke commands.

Is AHK capable of handling this task? If not, where should I go from here?

NOTE: I'm using Windows 11. The USB Piano is an Arturia Minilab MkII.

Arturia Minilab MkII, knobs 10 & 11:

[image]

UPDATE: I've done further research and it seems that I may be able to craft a solution using Python. The code below isn't returning any names for connected USB devices. Any thoughts?

```
    import mido



def find_midi_device():
    # Find the USB MIDI device
    for device in mido.get_input_names():
        if "Arturia" in device:
            return device
    return None


def main():
    device_name = find_midi_device()
    if device_name is None:
        print("USB MIDI device not found.")
        return

    print("Found USB MIDI device:", device_name)

    with mido.open_input(device_name) as port:
        print("Listening for MIDI messages. Turn the control knob on your device...")

        for message in port:
            if message.type == 'control_change':
                print("Control knob value:", message.value)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: To the close voter, this question is very on topic here. The actions are taking place on the computer, the keyboard doesn't likely need to be modified and so the question is about the software on the computer and possibly the interconnect between the keyboard and the computer. Also, it shows research and effort on the part of the asked, making it a better-built question that 90% of the first-time questions here.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've done further research and it seems that I may be able to craft a solution using Python.

Comment: If your computer has a keyboard [PS/2-Port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_port), you can try to insert your device in it using a PS/2-to-USB adapter and restart the computer. If the device is working, repeat the [KeyHistory procedure](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys). Don't forget to add `#InstallKeybdHook` to your script.

Comment: https://docs.midi-mixer.com/